# Rearranging data for quadtree/octree

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quadtree, octree

I am working on implementing a voxel octree raycaster, and the only thing left is rearranging the data to populate the leaf level of the octree, so that the data then can be averaged to build the lower levels of the tree.

I'm thinking in 2D (quadtree) initially for convenience. I have the data ordered like in the left in the drawing, and I am currently able to rearrange it like to the right. Example is `8x8`.

[image: Current]

However, I realized that I need to order the data in node order, like in the drawing below:

[image: Wanted]

In other words, I want to go from an array where the data correspond to indices like this:

```
[0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ... 63]
```

to an array that would have the data in this order:

```
[0  1  4  5  16 17 20 21 2  3 ... 63]
```

for an `8x8` quadtree example.

I can't figure out how to do it. My main problem is dealing with an arbitrary tree size. I could probably hard-code a set of nested loops if I knew the size beforehand, but that it obviously not a great or elegant solution. I'm thinking there might be a recursive way achieve it.

This it what my quick and dirty sketch for sorting the data in the way described in picture one. It basically works by keeping track of four positions in the original data, and then stepping these forward as the new array gets filled. As far as I have been able to tell, this works fine but is not extendable to my needs:

```
 int w = 8; 
  int[] before = new int[w*w*w];
  int[] after = new int[w*w*w];
  for (int i=0; i<w*w*w; i++) {
    before[i] = i;
  }
  int toFill = 0;
  int front = 0;
  int back = w;
  int frontZ = w*w;
  int backZ = w*w + w;
  do {
   for (int i=0; i<w/2; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<w/2; j++) {   
        after[toFill++] = front++;
        after[toFill++] = front++;
        after[toFill++] = back++;
        after[toFill++] = back++;

        after[toFill++] = frontZ++; 
        after[toFill++] = frontZ++; 
        after[toFill++] = backZ++;
        after[toFill++] = backZ++;
      }    
      front += w;
      back += w;
      frontZ += w;
      backZ += w;
    }
    front += w*w;
    back += w*w;
    frontZ += w*w;
    backZ += w*w;
  } while (toFill < w*w*w);
  for (int i=0; i<w*w*w; i++) {
    println("after " + i + " " + after[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Looks kind of like a Z-order curve ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve ) which makes sense given that you're talking about quad/oct trees.  That said, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Added what I've tried, and some further clarifications. It certainly looks like a Z-order curve! I'm also thinking that it might be easier to create a proxy tree, traverse it and use that order to fill the new structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the problem I stated, **phs** hinted me that it is called a Z-order curve. Thanks to that, I found this question: [Z-order-curve coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157685/z-order-curve-coordinates) where an algorithm for the 2D case is presented. I tried it, and it works.

Here are a few implementations of the 3D case as well: [How to compute a 3D Morton number (interleave the bits of 3 ints)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024754/how-to-compute-a-3d-morton-number-interleave-the-bits-of-3-ints)